# Does anybody have offline documentation for the GPS.NET library?

Tags: .net, gps

I'm considering using the [GPS.NET](http://gps3.codeplex.com) library in our CF.NET project, but I haven't been able to find any real documentation for it.

The company that developed this SDK used to publish the documentation on their website, but the website is long gone and the only part of that information that can be found (http://web.archive.org/web/20080327211746/www.geoframeworks.com/Documentation/Default.aspx) from what I've heard is only a small subset of the real thing.

Do you perhaps have the documentation in some offline form or know of a place on the internet where it can still be reached?